# Two Servers in One cluster, Public IPs, and many private subnets. Floating IP with HA?

Tags: networking, firewall, cluster, high-availability

We are working on a Debian based linux firewall setup, where we are planning to deploy 2 Physical Servers, Node A and Node B. They both would have Public IP address and 1 floating IP.

The question behind this cluster, we would like to create multiple small /30 subnets with 1 Gateway IP and 1 Host IP. Can we just assign the Gateway IPs to the floating Interface of the two servers, or we need to have 3 IPs in every subnets at least, 1 for Node A, 1 for Node B and another one for the internal floating, plus one for the server that is in that subnet?
Basically we would dont want to waste the additional IPs for both nodes, just for the floating and the Host itself.

Thank you!